# Adding "Appendices" before A,B,C in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I would like to add the word "Appendices" in my toc, before the Appendices A,B,C etc.

That is to say, I would like something like this:

```
1. Chapitre 1

2. Chapitre 2

Annexes
    A
    B
    C
```

Thank you.

p.s: I'm using the `appendix` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A look into the manual of `appendix` reveals: `\usepackage[toc]{appendix}` is what you want, most likely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[toc]{appendix}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Foobar}

\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Foo App}
  \chapter{Foobar App}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you. Actually I forgot to say that I want to write "Annexes"  (french) instead of "Appendices".

Comment: @Addon `\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}`

Comment: @Addon: Or `\usepackage[french]{babel}` should do this automatically, without `\renewcommand{\appendixname}`

Comment: I'm not sure `babel` would work here. The macro used by the `appendix` package is `\appendixtocname`, not `\appendixname`. But I can't test it now...